# Python : redirected message order

Tags: python, redirect, subprocess

I can redirect Python script output simply with ">" character in command line.
However, if Python script has subprocess.call(), the order of output lines is missed.

test.py

```
import subprocess

print("Message from Python... this should appear at 1st line")
subprocess.call(r"c:\src\python\redirect2\hi.bat")
```

hi.bat

```
@echo off
echo Message from batch file. this should appear at 2nd line.
```

Below is the message I expect.

```
C:\src\python\redirect2>\Python34\python.exe test.py

Message from Python... this should appear at 1st line
Message from batch file. this should appear at 2nd line.
```

However, once I redirect its output, the order of these lines got swapped.

```
C:\src\python\redirect2>\Python34\python.exe test.py > console.txt

C:\src\python\redirect2>type console.txt
Message from batch file. this should appear at 2nd line.
Message from Python... this should appear at 1st line
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this ?
Putting sleep() doesn't seem help. I'm using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use subprocess.Popen instead, so you can capture the output.

```
import subprocess

print("Message from Python... this should appear at 1st line")
p = subprocess.Popen("c:\src\python\redirect2\hi.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

print out
```

Comment: I chnaged the last line to print( out.decode(encoding='UTF-8') ). Otherwise, the end-of-line couldn't displayed correctly.

Comment: But why does it happen?